# Image and Sprite renderer cover the light component in Unity

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, canvas, sprite

[image]
[image]

As you can see, for some reasons the sprite renderer is covering the light component, though the light component is ahead it

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

I found a valid solution:
I created a new material and in the "shaders" section, I choose "Particles/Standard Unit".
I added this material to the image script of the background and all perfectly works!

[image]